# Cucumber tests are no longer running from a Maven context

Tags: maven, cucumber

With my latest commit, it seems I've somehow broken the ability to run my Cucumber tests.  I've tried to row back to no avail.  Can anyone see anything obvious?  It's a project with 2 modules and a parent pom. The build runs fine with no errors but 0 tests run.  I'm at a loss.

I've attached a screengrab of IntelliJ (forgive the crude paintjob to hide 'secrets'):

[image: IntelliJ]

I am using the following goal:

```
mvn verify -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/features/myCool.feature"
```

..so I can generate the cucumber report. My parent pom contains the following build phase:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>**/RunTest.java</includes>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>suitepoolthreadsize</name>
                        <value>10</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>parallel</name>
                        <value>methods</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>threadCount</name>
                        <value>10</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                        <value>30</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>cucumber-jvm-example</projectName>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
                        <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

EDIT: I've noticed a warning:

```
    [WARNING] C:\company-automation\blah-supplier-tests\target\cucumber.json does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

the feature file had the wrong name - doh!